# .emacs complains about undefined functions/variables event after byte-compile

Tags: use-package, treemacs

I use `use-package` and pulled in the `treemacs` package with the default settings. Then I byte-compiled my `.emacs`file. But I still get a warning saying:

```
the following functions might not be defined at runtime: treemacs--find-python3, treemacs-follow-mode, treemacs-filewatch-mode, treemacs-fringe-indicator-mode, treemacs-git-mode
```

I also tried to add these modes in the `:defines` parameter in `use-package`, but has no effect.

How to get rid of these warnings properly?

Comment: Use `require` instead of `use-package`, just ignore the warnings, or don’t bother byte-compiling your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, since I am using `use-package`, I think the easiest and safe way to get rid of the warnings is just to suppress them, like mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19507/12018)

Simply add this to the bottom of your **.emacs** file.

```
;; Local Variables:
;; byte-compile-warnings: (not free-vars noruntime)
;; End:
```

Answer (score 2):

use-package includes keywords to deal with this. The documentation https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package tells you what to do in this case under the heading **Byte-compiling your .emacs**

> Another feature of use-package is that it always loads every file that it can when .emacs is being byte-compiled. This helps to silence spurious warnings about unknown variables and functions.
>
> However, there are times when this is just not enough. For those times, use the :defines and :functions keywords to introduce dummy variable and function declarations solely for the sake of the byte-compiler:

```
(use-package texinfo
  :defines texinfo-section-list
  :commands texinfo-mode
  :init
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.texi$" . texinfo-mode)))
```

> If you need to silence a missing function warning, you can use :functions:

```
(use-package ruby-mode
  :mode "\\.rb\\'"
  :interpreter "ruby"
  :functions inf-ruby-keys
 :config
  (defun my-ruby-mode-hook ()
    (require 'inf-ruby)
    (inf-ruby-keys))

(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'my-ruby-mode-hook))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to those functions in your init file?

You can add the following to suppress the individual warnings:

```el
(declare-function treemacs--find-python3 "treemacs")
(declare-function treemacs-filewatch-mode "treemacs")
(declare-function treemacs-follow-mode "treemacs")
(declare-function treemacs-fringe-indicator-mode "treemacs")
(declare-function treemacs-git-mode "treemacs")
```